# How to separate number from a string

Tags: java, string, split

Need to seperate a number from a string

for example:
string a="Task123";
i need to seperate 123 as a single number from the string a

Comment: `String b = a.replaceAll("\\D+", "");` or parse the result to int if you need an integer

Comment: @BaskarAvinash You can post and accept an Answer to your own Question.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Task1234";
String number = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

return the number which contains your output.